# Why don't G+, Facebook and Twitter use text editors to share? Why would someone receive each separately?

Tags: javascript

I've seen sites use text editors as below:
[image]

What is the risk in using these? G+ receives images individually, others receive it all at once. Could someone shed some light on it?

Comment: My guess would be ease of use and not necessarily security concerns. Those sites generally live from the content itself and not from how it is presented. In that sense, letting the App decide how it should present it to the user is more straightforward for both the user to actually use and the site to display it in a consistent manner.

Comment: You should put your comment as an answer, I think it's a good one.

Comment: @CyrilN. - His comment is best left as a comment.  An answer should contained more then two sentences.

Comment: Not necesseraly, if it's straight, I believe more would be useless. But well, it's up tu @Mike to decide :)

Comment: @Sheriff, I confess I'm having a hard time understanding the question.  Can you say more about what in particular makes you think that using a text editor might pose a risk?  Also I did not understand what you mean by "receiving images individually" vs "all at once".  Sounds like others understood what you were asking, so I might be just dense... but it might help if you explained what aspect of this makes you think there may be some security or privacy risk and explained the context a bit more.

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better asked on http://ux.stackexchange.com/ unless the OP has a reason to believe this was not done due to security concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be ease of use and not necessarily security concerns. Those sites generally live from the content itself and not from how it is presented. In that sense, letting the App decide how it should present it to the user is more straightforward for both the user to actually use and the site to display it in a consistent manner.

Taken from my own comment, seeing as this is an answer and not a clarification.

Comment: you said `Those sites generally live from the content itself `. You mean they want to upload those specific files to their server to represent it later? Is that what you say? Correct me if am wrong. thanks.

Comment: Those services make their money (or keep their users if you prefer) by making it more attractive to them. Having a simple and clean interface helps focusing on the actual content (which is what people are interested in) instead of layout (bold, italic, alignment). Also, uploading files guarantees that the files will always be available. If you ever encountered old forum posts with dead links, you can see where the advantage is. Using a simple and clean interface again helps and encourages users to actually use those functions.

Comment: Basically, the majority of the people would never, for instance, post pictures if you had to upload them somewhere else and include those images later via an `<img>` tag or image link button on the WYSIWYG editor, hence why I guessed that it's a usability concern and not a security concern.